# Problema com acentuação cURL

Tags: php, mysql, codificação-de-caracteres, libcurl

Tenho um código onde envia dados via `cURL` para outra página dentro do servidor, só que estou com um problema... Ao enviar esses dados para a outra página, ela insere no MySQL só que ao ver o registro inserido no MySQL todas as palavras depois de qualquer acento fica em branco. Por exemplo, se eu envio **Programação** no MySQL só insere **Programa** o resto não envia.

**cURL.php**

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
$ch = curl_init();

extract($_POST); //Recebe do $.post() do jQuery

$data = array('dados'=>array('nome'=>$nome, 'tipo'=>$tipo));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://localhost/app2/api/api.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));

$output = curl_exec($ch);


echo json_decode($output);

curl_close($ch);
?>
```

**api.php**

```
<?php
...

$dados = $_POST["dados"];

$nome = $dados["nome"];
$tipo = $dados["tipo"];

$insere = mysql_query("INSERT INTO tabela VALUES (NULL, '".$nome."', '".$tipo."')");

...
?>
```

Comment: \[ Comentário obrigatório sobre [deprecação de `mysql_*`](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/579/por-que-n%C3%A3o-devemos-usar-fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es-do-tipo-mysql) e [injeção SQL](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3864/como-prevenir-inje%c3%a7%c3%a3o-de-c%c3%b3digo-sql-no-meu-c%c3%b3digo-php) \]

Comment: Mas o `$_POST` chega acentuado no `api.php`? Ou o problema é no `mysql_query`?

Comment: chega tudo acentuado corretamente

Comment: A sua base ta utf8 também ? e sua conexão está configurada como?

Comment: Então não é problema de cURL, mas de MySQL.

Comment: Consegui resolver: O Problema é que eu estava com `utf8_decode($variavel)` antes de inserir no banco, e fazendo isso ele colocava um caractere inválido no lugar de acento e não insere corretamente. Obrigado a todos!

Comment: Coloque isso como solução da sua pergunta, divide o pão seu com os outros, rs @AlissonAcioli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Já tentou utilizar conversão de UTF8 antes de enviar para o cURL ?

Aparentemente pode não ser necessário porém os valores vindos de um formulário podem não estar codificados em UTF-8 e isso causa o problema.

Tente isso:

```
...
extract($_POST); //Recebe do $.post() do jQuery

$nome = utf8_encode($nome);
$tipo = utf8_encode($tipo);

$data = array('dados'=>array('nome'=>$nome, 'tipo'=>$tipo));
...
```

Um outro detalhe que percebi no seu código é o uso do extract no POST;
Esse tipo de utilização não é recomendável. A própria documentação da função recomenda a não utilização:

> Warning
>   Do not use extract() on untrusted data, like user input (i.e. $_GET, $_FILES, etc.). If >you do, for example if you want to run old code that relies on register_globals >temporarily, make sure you use one of the non-overwriting flags values such as EXTR_SKIP >and be aware that you should extract in the same order that's defined in variables_order >within the php.ini. Fonte: [PHP: extract - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php)

Você pode alterar o código e fazer assim para ter mais segurança:

```
...
//extract($_POST); //Recebe do $.post() do jQuery

$nome = utf8_encode($_POST['nome']);
$tipo = utf8_encode($_POST['tipo']);

$data = array('dados'=>array('nome'=>$nome, 'tipo'=>$tipo));
...
```

Sucesso!